# How to make an logic to separate the data from SQL with Cakephp2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp-2.0

Currently, I have a site that shows a list of Developers name that I pulled out from the MySQL from the database in Cakephp2. What I want to achieve is to separate "Developers" into two types like "developer" and "programmer". I tried to give an extra field for the id to separate the developers with the programmers in the table that contains the developer's name. But I'm stuck with how I can do this. My explanation might be confusing so I will put the sample of what I want to do below. Some tips and examples with be a great help. I would love to hear from you.

```
    Currently, Employee table consitsts of list of names
     of all developers and is retrieved and displayed in cakephp2.
             (Developer) 
                    ------------------------------
                        Tim 
                        Jim 
                        Joe 
                        Blake 
                        Mike
                        Ron
                ------------------------------

            Now, I want to separate the Developers into two parts "Developer" and "Programmer" maybe by adding a programmer_id field .

                (Developers) 
                ------------------------------
                        Tim  
                        Jim   ← programmer_id
                        Joe
                        Blake
                        Mike ← programmer_id
                        Ron
                 ------------------------------

Want to show the separated data in cakephp2 like the following.


                (Developer)
                        Tim 
                        Joe
                        Blake
                        Ron

                ------------------------------
                (Programmer)
                        Jim 
                        Mike
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting exactly what you are asking but as per your table structure you can do something like this.

```
     developer   Tim  
     programer   Jim   ← programmer_id
     developer   Joe
     developer   Blake
     programer   Mike ← programmer_id
     developer   Ron

  $developer = $this->Employee->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Employee.category' => 'developer')
    ));

  $programmer = $this->Employee->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Employee.category' => 'programmer')
    ));
```